FASM/NASM/GCC don't optimize [RBP + reg] addressing modes to use RBP as the index, costing an extra byte of code size?
I have assembled the (somewhat weird) instruction ADD EAX, DWORD PTR [RBP + RAX*1] with GCC, FASM and NASM. All of them produce the following suboptimal output
0:  03 44 05 00             add    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp+rax*1+0x0]

The 0x0 displacement is added since RBP may not be used as base register without it.
However, the same instruction could - as far as I can tell - be encoded as
0:  03 04 28                add    eax,DWORD PTR [rax+rbp*1]

Base and Index registers are swapped here, which works as long as the scale is 1.
In 64-bit mode, both SS and DS have the same base and no limit, so it doesn't matter that RAX implies the DS segment while base=RBP implies SS, does it?  (It's also generally a safe optimization in 32-bit code using a flat memory model.)

I would understand if this was an optimization these assemblers just don't do, but that's not the case either.
For example, NASM and FASM turn ADD EAX, DWORD PTR [RBP + RSP*1] into
0:  03 04 2c                add    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+rbp*1]

Here, base and index registers were swapped, allowing for the SIB encoding without a displacement.  (And making it possible to encode at all, since RSP can never be an index.)

Is this just an optimization these assemblers don't do, or is there a reason why they chose not to?

In 64 bit mode it should not matter, but in 32 bit mode one uses DS the other uses SS segment so they are not interchangeable as far as the assembler can prove (they usually are in practice due to SS = DS). However rsp and rbp both use SS so those are safe to swap. As I said, it does not matter in 64 bit but I suspect the limitation is mistakenly applied in this case too.

@Jester: Am I remembering correctly that add eax, [rbp + rax] will #SS fault on a non-canonical address, vs. add eax, [rax + rbp] will #GP?  So there is a potentially observable difference in behaviour other than the code-size difference, although not one that matters in 99.9% of cases even in hand-written asm.

[rbp + rsp*1] isn't encodeable because RSP can never be an index, so it had to swap or report an error.  (rbp not allowed as SIB base?

@Jester very interesting theory that this might be due to the assembler not making the assumption SS=DS. That would definitely explain the behavior. I have not tested the exceptions, but that also makes sense, and tracks with what I have read in the manual.

@PeterCordes that's true - in that case, the only two choices seem to be to reject the instruction or swap index and base. It was just an example to show that these assemblers can swap them in at least some cases.

I'm trying to remember - I know that base/limit calculations do not apply in 64-bit mode, but is there any obscure way to, for instance, make DS or SS invalid, or make the corresponding segment read-only or privileged or anything like that?

@NyxCode: Yeah, it's definitely interesting that they're willing to swap at all, so there is some code in there to check for it.  But perhaps just to check for [er]sp being an unscaled index and making it the base instead.  NASM will also swap add eax, [rcx + rsp*1], so it's not checking for that both registers imply the same segment base.  It's only swapping when necessary to make the source instruction encodeable, not as an optimization.  Since it's not strictly equivalent to a valid instruction that could appear in asm source, even if you special case BITS 64

Although 64-bit code generally uses null selectors in practice, it looks like you can also use a non-null selector, in which case, if I read correctly, checks are performed against the type and privilege from the segment descriptor.  So for instance, if DS pointed to a read-only segment, then mov [rbp+rax*1], ecx would not fault but mov [rax+rbp*1], ecx would.
